# Bringing SQL into a crystal formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

Hello I am working in crystal and am wanting to add a formula field called Group 1, and want to use SQL query like this:

```
CASE '{?Group 1}'                   
            WHEN 'Location' THEN (CASE WHEN COALESCE(TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1, TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2) IS NULL THEN '*Unspecified Location'
                WHEN TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_1 IS NULL THEN CONCAT('*Unknown Location', CONCAT(' [',CONCAT(COALESCE(TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1, TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2),']')))
                WHEN TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2 IS NULL THEN CONCAT('*Unnamed Location', CONCAT(' [',CONCAT(TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_1,']')))
                ELSE TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2 END)                        
            ELSE NULL END GROUP_1
```

Not entirely sure how this translates into crystal. Any help would be great. 
Thank you

Ok I reworked the formula and came up with:

```
IF {?Group1} = "Location" THEN
    IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1}) THEN "*Unspecified Location" ELSE
    IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2}) THEN "*Unspecified Location" ELSE
    IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_1}) THEN "*Unknown Location" ELSE
    IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2}) THEN "*Unnamed Location"
            ELSE {TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2}
```

I think this might work. Would you agree or is there a better way?

Comment: If else is equal to case in crystal reports...try to change using if else statements

Comment: What about the WHEN? What would this be equal to?

Comment: See this will become nested if else..like if inside if...try it else explain the query by splitting into parts will try to answer

Comment: Ok I updated the question.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Comment: Yes Siva that works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your conversion is almost correct need some changes check below.

```
        IF {?Group1} = "Location" THEN
        (
            IF (ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1}) or ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2})) 
    THEN "*Unspecified Location" 
        ELSE IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_1}) 
        THEN "*Unknown Location " &IIF((ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1}) or ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2})),{TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_1},{TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN_NAME_2})
        ELSE IF ISNULL({TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2}) 
THEN "*Unnamed Location " & {TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_1}
        )
                    ELSE {TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN_NAME_2}
```